# Should events be handled in the Presenter/Controller?

Tags: c#, mvp

Say I have an MVP app. Should the Presenter handle events raised by the view.  For example, please see the code below:

```
public void TextBox_TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

and the code below:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

If it should be handled by the presenter, then is it better to:

1) Have an event handler in the view that forwards to a method in the presenter.
2) Handle the event in the presenter directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep your code organized and maintainable, I would say it is better to handle the event in the Presenter. The purpose of the view is to display information to the user. The purpose of the presenter is to execute logic and work as a middle man between data and users.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be handled by the view, as the view is only responsible for defining the layout of the UI.

Also, you should go with 2, handling it in the presenter directly. The presenter should also, in my opinion be responsible for wiring up the event; the views knowledge of the presenter should be minimized.

```
public class MyPresenter
{
     public void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          view.button.OnClick += Button_Click;
     }

     public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //do something
     }
}
```

Another approach would be mediating the event through the model, instead of the view directly:

```
public void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    model.OnClick += Button_Click;
}
```

Then, trigger the model's on click event in the view.